# Rebase the feature branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, rebase

I have deleted the copy of my feature branch from my local machine. After that, I have cloned my feature branch and did the modification there, and send the merge request to master. Now GitLab is asking me to do rebase. But when I am trying to do it, it fails and says "Rebase failed. Please rebase locally". How can I do it now?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by following these steps: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/git_rebase.html#regular-rebase

1. Fetch the latest changes from `master`: `git fetch origin master`
2. Checkout your feature branch: `git checkout my-feature-branch`
3. Rebase it against `master`: `git rebase origin/master`
4. Force push to your branch